# vbus regulator device tree

Tags: linux, device-tree

can someone explain the device tree settings? What they will do on i.MX6 Processor?

Thanks!

```
vbus1_regulator: regulator@1 {
    compatible = "regulator-fixed";
    regulator-name = "vbus1_regulator";
    regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
    gpio = <&gpio3 22 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    enable-active-high;
};


&usbotg {
    vbus-supply = <&vbus1_regulator>;
    dr_mode = "host";
    status = "okay";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The USB protocol defines two roles - host and client. With USB OTG (on-the-go) a device can have both host and client capabilities. See:

http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1822

In order for the device to work as a host, it needs to provide power for the client device connected to it, as required by the USB standard.

That being said, the *&usbotg* node is:

1. Using the _vbus1_regulator_ as USB power supply.
2. Forcing the USB OTG port to work as host by setting the *dr_mode* property to *host*.
3. Enabling the node by setting the status to *okay*.

Please see the Linux kernel device-tree bindings documentation for more details:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/usb/fsl-usb.txt

And the *vbus1_regulator* node is:

1. Using the kernel driver compatible to *regulator-fixed*: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/regulator/fixed.c?h=v4.19-rc1#n196
2. Setting the name of the regulator to *vbus1_regulator*.
3. Defining the minimum and maximum voltages to the same value of 5000000 micro volts, which as the same as 5 volts. Both are the same due to the nature of a fixed voltage regulator - you have a single fixed output voltage value.
4. Using a GPIO pin (declared elsewhere) to control the regulator (switch on/off).
5. Defining that the GPIO level must be high in order to activate the regulator. If this property is omitted, that it is assumed that the regulator is active on logic level low.

Please see the Linux kernel device-tree bindings documentaiton for more details:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/regulator/fixed-regulator.txt